# CiviMembership not on Administer Menu

Tags: civimember

My CiviCRM does not seem to have CiviMembership. It is not listed on the administer menu on the top menu.

How do I proceed if I want to use CiviMembership?

Answer (score 7):

Go to administer > system settings > components and enable it.